# Phalcon PHP Ajax error model

Tags: php, ajax, phalcon

When i'm trying to save my model like this `if( !$myModel->save() )` I have to surround in try catch my condition if I want to get the errors messages... I can't check if the save() is false, because this will not returns the errors.

How can I do to get `$myModels->getMessages()` without using try catch ?

I want to do like this [example](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/models.html#creating-updating-records) and return json_encode if the save doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

[The example from the docs](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/models.html#creating-updating-records), shows you how to get the messages after you save your `$myModel`

```
$robot       = new Robots();
$robot->type = "mechanical";
$robot->name = "Astro Boy";
$robot->year = 1952;

if ($robot->save() == false) {
    echo "Umh, We can't store robots right now: \n";
    // get the messages of the saved Robot.
    foreach ($robot->getMessages() as $message) {
        echo $message, "\n";
    }
} else {
    echo "Great, a new robot was saved successfully!";
}
```